# picture on the bottom right cornor of image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a little icon on the right bottom corner of the image. So the image gets a little icon on the bottom right cornor of the picture.

```
<div> 
<div class="tab-pane" id="activity">
    <div class="post clearfix">
    <?php 
    $suppport = $app->get_supportpage();
     foreach($suppport as $support){
    ?>
    <div class="user-block" style="margin-top:5px;">
      <img style="margin-top:3%;"class="img-circle" src="/assets/images/profielfotos/64hond.jpg">       
      <span class="username"><a href=""><?php echo $support['van_naam'] ?></a></span>
      <span class="description">                                      
<div style="  white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; max-width: 250px;">
<b><?php echo $support['bericht']; ?></b><br>
31 minuten geleden<p style="float:right;"><?php echo $support['type']; ?></p></div>
</span>

     </div><hr>
    <?php } ?>
   </div>
  </div>                            
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I assume that `64hond.jpg` is the image you want to put a little icon on, but I can't tell what the icon is. Is it in your code at all? You also forgot to explain what problem you have with that.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the icon is not in their you can just take an font awesome icon or something. And the problem is that i  cant get it to work. To little icon on the bottom right cornor of the big image

Answer (score 2):

use div instead of img tags, and use a background-image:url('path') for your images and do a position:absolute on your icon

```css
.image{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  background-color:lime;
  background-image: url(//www.w3schools.com/Html/pic_trulli.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.image .icon i{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px;
  font-size: 33px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="image">
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-car"></i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you make it for my situation?

Comment: I just edited my post,
all you need to do is change the imge path for your image,

also i heard your icon was a font awsome icon so thats what i did